# Axios redirect 308 not working (CORS error)

Tags: nginx, redirect, axios

We are implementing short URLs to redirect on our project.

I do an API request to my server using axios, with the info on the short url.
The server responds with a redirect status `308` succesffuly.

I see in the response headers, the location parameter (to redirect to) is correct.
And we have also set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

But the redirect does not follow through...

After recieving the 308; the browser attempts a preflight `OPTIONS` request to the redirect URL, followed by a `GET` request to the redirect URL.
Both of these return an error.
The preflight request error: `CORS Misssing Allow Origin`. And the GET request gives error: `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI`

---

Not sure what the issue is. Is it on the front-end, or on the server-side?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!